# Need to make a function like .lstrip

Tags: python-3.3

I need to make a function like .lstrip. I have already completed a function that counts the number of occurrences of a letter. Can this function be used to help me complete this function which i will refer to as *my_lstrip*? The only problem I'am having is with how to remove a letter/word from a string, I just can't think of any way....

Just to refresh anyone's memory: lstrip removes the leading occurrences of a string.

I don't think indexing would be a choice but I'am still thinking, anyone's help would be appreciated. I already completed a function like length, count, and find so if any combinations of these can be used here then great! If you need further information let me know, thank you. If i come up with anything I'll post the code so others can examine it and see my mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since strings in Python are immutable you cannot remove anything from a string. What you can do is to create new string and omit some leading characters for example like this:

```
def my_lstrip(p, s):
     """Remove leading occurences of p from s
     Keyword arguments:
     p - pattern to remove
     s - input string

     >>> my_lstrip('f', 'foo')
     'oo'
     >>> my_lstrip('foo', 'foobar')
     'bar'
     >>> my_lstrip('foo', 'foofoofoobar')
     'bar'
     >>> my_lstrip('o', 'ooooofoo')
     'foo'
     >>> my_lstrip('fooo', 'foo')
     'foo'
     >>> my_lstrip('bar', 'foo')
     'foo'
     """
     return  my_lstrip(p, s[len(p):]) if s.startswith(p) else s
```

It can be done more effectively (without creating new string each time you get a match) but I will leave that as a exercise for you.